# The use of the definite article before the name of a language in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please if it is necessary to use *the* before *English* in the following sentence.

> (**The**) English spoken in Australia is slightly different than (**the**) English spoken in America in terms of vocabulary and pronunciation.

I think that *the* is necessary there because it is clearly specified what type of English in what country.

Comment: In the maddening world of English articles, the definite article is optional. The likely reason is that "spoken in X" is restrictive.

Comment: To me the sentence sounds slightly strange without the articles, but I agree with @user105719 that they're not required grammatically. Maddening indeed.

Comment: Australian English is slightly different from American English.